return multi-row (1 row per call) output from function and use it in procedure
I have scenario where I need to:

pull data from a table
Perform calculations
return six columns

In the next step, I have procedures which output columnar reports. This is where this function needs to be invoked inline based on input parameters and the output (All 6 columns) needs to be part of the report.
I have tried 2 approaches for this:

Pipelined function returning only one based on Table Type defined at schema level;

create or replace FUNCTION FUNCNAME(INPUT_PARAMS)
    RETURN TABLE_TYPE
    PIPELINED
    AUTHID current_user
AS
    LOCAL_TABLE_TYPE VARIABLE TABLE_TYPE;
BEGIN
    ----Populate the collection
            select TABLE_TYPE(Collection elements)
                bulk collect into LOCAL_TABLE_TYPE
                from TABLENAME;
    
    FOR i IN 1..TABLE_TYPE.count LOOP
        PIPE ROW LOCAL_TABLE_TYPE(i).<Elements>;
    END LOOP;    
END FUNCNAME;
/

This approach failed as pipelined function can not be used in a subquery.

Function returning ref cursor
This approach while being better than previous one returns output (all columns as a with header, another line with only '---' and then the columns as singular unit which needs to be parsed inside the calling function. Splitting of the columns again errs out.

create or replace FUNCTION FUNC_NAME(INPUT_PARAMS)
    return SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
    V_STATS_OUTPUT  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    open V_STATS_OUTPUT for 
            select * from table_name;
END FUNC_NAME;

Can any of you please help?

"This approach failed as pipelined function can not be used in a subquery." Yes they can fiddle

Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an English explanation for the logic that you are trying to implement; some syntactically valid code; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment, your question: is very vague about what the actual problem is; contains invalid code snippets (your code is a mix of PL/SQL and pseudo-code which will not compile); and you make unfounded statements about what is not possible. All these makes it very difficult to know what you want help with.

I suggest exploring the OUTER APPLY join operator. For every row in the resultset prior to performing this join, Oracle will re-execute the row source (subquery, function, table-function call, etc.) and can pass in through multiple nested levels whatever inputs are needed from the outer resultset.
For a single row function:
SELECT table1.*,
       table2.*,
       x.rec.col1,
       x.rec.col2,
       x.rec.col3,
       x.rec.col4,
       x.rec.col5,
       x.rec.col6
  FROM table1
       JOIN table2 on table2.key = table1.key
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT FUNCNAME(table1.attr1,table2.attr2) rec FROM dual) x

Your function would return an object:
create type myobj_type as object (col1 integer, col2 integer, col3 integer, col4 integer, col5 integer, col6 integer);
/

create or replace function funcname(attr1,attr2)
  return myobj_type
as
  myobj myobj_type;
begin
  select myobj_type(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)
    into myobj
    from ....;

  return myobj;
end;

For a multiple-row (table) pipelined function, make sure to use a single pipe per row, not per column. All six columns should be piped together. Also, use cursors that loop through results rather than bulk collecting into a local collection. One of the primary benefits to pipelined functions is you don't have to consume PGA memory for the entire resultset - just for each row. The moment you pre-stage the result in a collection with bulk collect, you eliminate that benefit and also delay the first row emission.
create type myobj_type as object (col1 integer, col2 integer, col3 integer, col4 integer, col5 integer, col6 integer);
/
create type mytab_type as table of myobj_type;
/
create or replace function funcname(attr1,attr2)
  return mytab_type pipelined
as
begin
  for rec_cursor in (select myobj_type(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) myobj
                       from ....)
  loop
    pipe row (rec_cursor.myobj);
  end loop;
end;

Then use it with OUTER APPLY, either using the fuller syntax which clarifies to the reader that it is a table function:
SELECT table1.*,
       table2.*,
       x.col1,
       x.col2,
       x.col3,
       x.col4,
       x.col5,
       x.col6
  FROM table1
       JOIN table2 on table2.key = table1.key
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT *
                      FROM FUNCNAME(table1.attr1,table2.attr2)) x

Or use the shorthand syntax. Oracle implicitly adds the SELECT * FROM for you:
SELECT table1.*,
       table2.*,
       x.col1,
       x.col2,
       x.col3,
       x.col4,
       x.col5,
       x.col6
  FROM table1
       JOIN table2 on table2.key = table1.key
       OUTER APPLY (FUNCNAME(table1.attr1,table2.attr2)) x


Thanks a lot Paul, let me try and revert on this.

It's working exactly as described Paul. Thank you for this crisp solution.
